# Energy can be created

Tags: special-relativity, energy-conservation, inertial-frames, piezoelectric

Consider a device which converts kinetic energy into electrical energy ( just like piezoelectric generator). Now I install this on two trains of very high mass approaching each other (moving in opposite direction at 100 m/s). I am going to do two studies. In thile first study, I have two people in each train and ask them to shoot at the the piezoelectric generator installed in their own trains (assume bullet velocity is 25 m/s). They will get electrical energy equal to the kinetic energy of the bullet (assuming 100% efficency). In second study, I ask the people to shoot at the piezoelectric generators installed in each others trains. Now the bullets hit the generator at 125 m/s while in first case it is just 25 m/s. So I think that the electrical energy created in second case is very high when compared to the first case.. So energy can be created... I know this sounds crazy. But I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Energy is not created. The difference between your two situations is in the **final kinetic energy of the two trains**.

When you fire the gun, it exerts a force on your body; to prevent your sliding across the floor, your feet exert a force on the train. Exerting this force very slightly changes the kinetic energy of the train. In addition, when the bullet is stopped by the piezoelectric generator, the generator has to exert a force on the bullet; by Newton's Third Law, the bullet therefore exerts a force on the generator. In order to keep the generator from sliding across the floor, the generator must *also* exert a force on the train, which will change its kinetic energy slightly.

When you fire the bullet into the generator on your own train, the force exerted by your feet and the force exerted by the generator are pointed **opposite** to each other (for example, if the generator is in the front of the train and you are behind it, then the force exerted on the train by your feet points backward, while the force exerted on the train by the generator points forward). In contrast, when you fire the bullet into the generator on the other train, the force exerted by your feet and the force exerted by the *other* bullet on *your own* generator are pointed in the **same direction** (the force on the train from each of their feet is pointed backward, and the force exerted by the bullet hitting the generator from the other side is *also* pointed backward).

So, in the first case, the two forces cancel out, and each train doesn't change speed or kinetic energy. In the second case, the two forces add together, and both trains *slow down* very slightly. The extra electrical energy you get in the second case is extracted from the kinetic energy of the trains.

Comment: if in the 1st case the train doesnt change speed, then where does the energy generated by the piezo comes from, the gun powder?.

Comment: @ManudeHanoi Yes, the electrical energy comes from the kinetic energy of the bullet, which comes from the chemical energy of the gunpowder (of course, there is also inevitably a lot of energy that is converted to heat and sound in the process, too, which means that only a small fraction of the chemical energy in the gunpowder is actually recoverable as electrical energy).

Comment: @probably_someone I agree with you,but this raises another doubt in me. Consider two trains moving at different velocity. The piezoelectric generators encounter two different bullets at same velocity( for observers inside the train, velocity of incoming bullet is same but different for observers outside). After completing the conversion of energy will the two trains have same loss in kinetic energy??

Comment: @Ironman I'm not sure I understand your scenario. Are both people shooting the other train's generator twice?

Comment: @probably_someone No this is completely different. The observers just observe two bullets coming toward them. Let us say that train A moves at 50m/s and bullet comes towards it at 50m/s. The train B moves at 75 m/s and bullet comes at 25 m/s. So both observers inside train will see the bullet coming at 100 m/s. My question is, will the both trains loose same kinetic energy when the bullet hit the piezoelectric generators at 100 m/s

Comment: @Ironman Yes, the two trains will lose the same amount of kinetic energy. To see why, it's important to remember what it means to "stop" a bullet in this context: a bullet that is stopped by the piezoelectric generator is _moving with the same velocity as the train_. The amount by which the bullet's velocity changes in order to move with the train is the same in both cases; therefore, the momentum transfer to each train is the same, which means that the force exerted on each train is the same, which means that the loss in kinetic energy of each train is the same.

Comment: @probably_someone yes, that is exactly what I expected. But there is a problem with your  1st answer. Take two trains moving towards each other at 50 m/s. If they shoot bullet inside  their own train the generated energy =0.5*m*50^2.but if they shoot at the other train the energy generated is =0.5*m*100^2. If m=2kg change in energy =100^2-50^2..now let the trains move at 75 m/s and  the bullet is shot at 25 m/s.The energy difference just as  above case will be 100^2-25^2.second case has more energy generated but as u said train looses same energy in both case. So there is some contradiction